# Wordpress Rest API Post request from AMP

Tags: posts, api, json

I am trying to figure out how to send a post request to a WP Rest API function on an AMP Page.

The endpoint requires 2 fields, post_id & nonce.

`/wp-json/wordpress-popular-posts/v2/views/[post_id]` as per the guide on https://github.com/cabrerahector/wordpress-popular-posts/wiki/8.-REST-API-Endpoints

Now the task here is how to send a request from the AMP page to this endpoint. My theme offers the ability to add custom html/javascript/CSS code to the AMP page.

But how can we get the nonce and post_id dynamically using Javascript?

Can the below code help me solve the issue?

```
$.ajax({
    url: foo,
    method: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", wpApiSettings.nonce);
    },
    data: {
        "foo": bar
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    // your custom code
});
```

Comment: [Here's how the nonce is set in wp_default_scripts](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/99396f6c868b4b332aa08eba7d77706cc8811b6f/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L817). I guess your AMP page doesn't use the default scripts?

Comment: this is a php script, looking for javascript for AMP

Comment: WordPress Nonce is set by PHP and then passed across to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to localize the nonce here's how: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/